# Работа с чекбоксами

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть данный код, работает с чекбоксами:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var on_prefix = "chekbox-on";
            var off_prefix = "chekbox-off";

            $(document).ready(function()

            {
                $('.check_f').hide();
                $('.check').click(function(){
                    var index = $('.check').index(this);
                    var imgsrc=$(this).attr('src');
                    if ($('.check_f').eq(index).attr('checked')) {
                        $(this).attr('src',imgsrc.replace(on_prefix,off_prefix));
                        $('.check_f').eq(index).removeAttr('checked');
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr('src',imgsrc.replace(off_prefix,on_prefix));
                        $('.check_f').eq(index).attr('checked','true');
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Чекбокс имеет вид

```
<div class="checks">
                <div><img class="check" src="images/1_chekbox-off.png"><input type="checkbox" name="check_del[]" value="бла бла бла" class="check_f" /><span class="centerspan">бла бла бла</span></div>
</div>
```

Но есть одна проблема в обозревателях IE, Mozilla и Opera: чек бокс работает, только дважды непрерывно клацать по нему нельзя. Помогите решить проблему, в Safari и Chrome только работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у меня [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/2GGc8/) в мозилле.

Comment: Проблему решил более новой версией js, спасибо за подсказку -)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что по двойному щелчку происходит событие dblclick. Поэтому попробуйте навесить еще одно событие:

```
$('.check').click(...).dblclick(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```